# LiveValidation - Change validation message to picture?

Tags: javascript, css, livevalidation

LiveValidation is JavaScript library for validating data. I'm using it to validate a form as the user inputs information. At the moment the validation message that appears is set as follows:

```
var username = new LiveValidation('username', { validMessage: 'Valid Username.', wait: 500});
```

However, I want to change it from saying "Valid Username." to simply displaying a green tick image. I have tried to do this by changing the CSS of the valid message area to the following:

```
.LV_valid
{
    background-image: url('green_tick.gif');
    font-size:10px;
    color:#33CC33;
}
```

This causes green ticks to be displayed along the entire message thats printed, and since the image is only 11x11 it fits in around 5 or 6 images. I have tried removing the valid message, but then it prints the default "Thankyou" message from the LiveValidation.js file. I tried changing the default message to be blank also, but then nothing is displayed at all. I also tried using the image location as the message but this just caused the actaul location text to be displayed.

Does anyone know how to display an image instead of text?

See the library here: http://livevalidation.com/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Sorry for reviving this post.. but there is the answer for those who need it.
It work for me...

```
.LV_valid
{
    display: inline-block;       
    color: transparent;
    text-indent: 100%; 
    background-image: url('right.png');
    background-repeat: no-repeat;
    overflow: hidden;
}

.LV_invalid
{
    display: inline-block;       
    color: transparent;
    text-indent: 100%; 
    background-image: url('wrong.png');
    background-repeat: no-repeat;
    overflow: hidden;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

This CSS should do what you want:

```
.LV_valid
{
    background-image: url('green_tick.gif');
    width: 0;
    height: 0;
    padding: 11px 11px 0 0;
    overflow: hidden;
}
```

Explanation: Those width, height, and overflow values hide all of the element's content, and the padding values add and 11x11 space in a way that doesn't allow the content to show, but does allow the background to show.

jsFiddle (using a different picture, of course): http://jsfiddle.net/uqRQp/

Comment: In this situation. When this solution is implemented, no image is visible.

Comment: Then I would think that your image URL is wrong.  The image URL needs to be relative to the stylesheet.  Is the "green_tick.gif" image in the same folder as the stylesheet?

Comment: The image url is correct as it displays in the background when a confirmation message is entered in the javascript.

Comment: I didn't mean to delete the confirmation message.  Leave the confirmation message there, and include my CSS (along with `display: inline-block;` as Daniel mentioned - he is correct that that's needed for a `span`).

Comment: The question Brilliand is asking is relevant - is the green_tick.gif image in *the same folder* as the the CSS file containing this rule?

Comment: Yes got it. Thankyou both so much. My problem was not leaving the message in the javascript. I am awarding the bounty to Daniel Attfield as his answer was slightly more comprehensive and he invested time talking me through it.

Answer (score 1):

I'd combine `background-repeat: no-repeat` with something to push the text out of sight:

```
.LV_valid
{
    /* This ensures the element is displayed as a block-level element
    so that all the following CSS rules apply. */        
    display: inline-block;          

    /* This displays your image, but only once. */
    background-image: url('green_tick.gif');
    background-repeat: no-repeat;

    /* This pushes the text out of the way so it can't be seen. */
    height: 0px !important;
    height: /**/ 11px; /* IE consistency hack */
    padding-top: 11px;
    overflow: hidden;
}
```

Comment: No image is visible when I implement this solution. I think this may have to be done using javascript. Thanks for your input though :0)

Comment: What kind of element is the .LV_valid class applied to? It may be you'd need a few more CSS rules to get the element to co-operate.

Comment: If it's not a block level element, you'll need to add either 'display: block;' or 'display: inline-block' depending on your layout requirements to get this fix to work - see here: http://jsfiddle.net/pRRXz/2/

Comment: The javascript creates a span to which the class is applied. How it does this, I don't know as I am unfamiliar with javascript.

Comment: The javascript library can be found here livevalidation.com

Comment: I've modified the answer to include the 'display: inline-block;' rule, so that your span (which is an inline element) is rendered as a block, so all the CSS rules can be successfully applied to it. Let me know how you get on.

Comment: Tried it without success. Still no image visible.

Answer (score 0):

check this link it may help : http://andreaslagerkvist.com/jquery/live-validation/#jquery-plugin-example-code

```
jQuery('#jquery-live-validation-example').liveValidation({
validIco:    WEBROOT + 'aFramework/Modules/Base/gfx/jquery.liveValidation-valid.png', 
invalidIco: WEBROOT + 'aFramework/Modules/Base/gfx/jquery.liveValidation-invalid.png', 
required:    ['name', 'email', 'foo'], 
fields:        {foo: /^\S.*$/}
```

});

this is a jquery plugin for validation  called jQuery Live Validation as you can see it has validIco and invalidIco who are actualy the image 2 display if it's invalid or valid

Comment: Short version: Instead of using `validMessage`, use `validIco`.  This does seem like the proper way to handle this specific problem.

Comment: Thanks for your input, however this solution seems to be unrelated to the Livevalidation plugin that I am currently using. Please see the link http://livevalidation.com/

Comment: yes i know it's a different plugin i thought maybe you could use it instead of the one you already  using

Comment: I appreciate the suggestion but the features provided by the library I am currently using are quite extensive and fit my requirements really well. I would ideally like to find a solution specifically for this.